# Export/import of custom panels

Tags: visual-studio

I created my own panel.
How can I export and import it to another Visual Studio?
Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-x) 17.5.3.

[image]

---

## Update-1

**Pic-1**

[image]

**Pic-2**
[image]

**Pic-3**
[image]

**Pic-4**
[image]

---

## Update-2

**Pic-1**
[image]

**Pic-2**
[image]

**Pic-3**
[image]

**Pic-4**
[image]

Comment: It is barely recognizable to English eyes, but it looks to me like you made a visual studio *extension*.  That is supposed to generate a .vsix file, you'd then simply copy it to another machine and install it.

Comment: @HansPassant See Update-1. Did I manage to formulate the question in more detail?

Comment: how did you create the panel?

Comment: @DanielA.White See **Update-2**.